# How to Remove Brackets from the Kotlin Array List

Tags: arrays, string, kotlin, arraylist

I have a method like this. I want to remove the brackets of the array list when I take the output.

```
fun getAddOnNamesList(): ArrayList<String>? {
  if (!addOns.isNullOrEmpty()) {
    val addOnName = ArrayList<String>()
    addOnName.clear()
    for (addOnCat in addOns!!) {
      if (addOnCat.addon.mIsSelected)
        addOnName.add(addOnCat.addon.name + "\n")
    }
    Log.e("TAG", "getAddOnsList: $addOnName")
    return addOnName
  }
  return null
}
```

Comment: What brackets do you mean? Can you share your output?

Comment: outputlike this display [Text1,Text2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun getAddOnNamesList(): ArrayList<String>? {
  if (addOns.isNullOrEmpty()) {
    return null
  } else {
    val addOnNames = addOns.filter { it.addon.mIsSelected }.map { it.addon.name } as ArrayList
    val addOnNamesString = addOnNames.joinToString(",")
    Log.e("TAG", "getAddOnsList: $addOnNamesString")
    return addOnNames
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can output desired ArrayList without brackets by using `joinToString()` method, e.g.:

```kotlin
val list = arrayListOf("Text1", "Text2")
val string = list.joinToString(separator = ",")
```